# prove or disprove: For a prime number p, there is a positive integer n such that $p+1 $= $n^2$ if and only if $ p = 3.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove or disprove: For a prime number p, there is a positive integer n such that $p+1 $= $n^2$ if and only if $ p = 3.$

first im trying to proof if p is prime number there is positive integer n such that $p+1=n^2$ implies $p=3$

suppose there is positive n integer such that $p+1=n^2$ and prove that $p=3$.
$p=n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$
since $p$ is prime $n-1=1$,$ n = 2 $
$p+1=4$
$p=3$
hence it is proved that $p=3$

now if $p=3$ implies there is positive integer n such that $p+1=n^2 $ 
$p=3$ and p is prime 
$p+1=n^2$,
$4=n^2$,
$n2$ or $n=-2$
hence it is proved that there is positive integer $n$ such that $p+1=n^2 $

is my proof correct?
and also for prime number can i write $n+1=1$ instead $n-1=1$?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: No, you couldn't write $n+1=1$ if I understand what you're asking.  If $p=(n-1)(n+1)$ then one of the factors is $1$ and the other is $p$.  It must be the smaller one that is $1$, so $n-1=1$

Comment: A clearer way to say it is $p=(n-1)(n+1)$, that is $p$ us a product of two numbers.  Therefore $p$ cannot be a prime unless one of the factors $=1$